# Postfix spf - delivers spoofing emails. Not fail

Tags: postfix-mta, spf, spoofing, dmarc

I started receiving spoofing emails. So I set up my server and domain but I still receive emails. SPF is not rejecting emails.

Can anyone help?

## dns records

```
myserver.com.   IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx a:myserver.com ip4:50.111.111.111 -all"

_dmarc.myserver.com.    IN  TXT "v=DMARC1; p=reject; fo=1; ri=3600; pct=100; rua=mailto:info@myserver.com; ruf=mailto:info@myserver.com
```

/etc/postfix-policyd-spf-python/policyd-spf.conf

```
debugLevel = 1

HELO_reject = Fail
Mail_From_reject = Fail

PermError_reject = False
TempError_Defer = False

skip_addresses = 127.0.0.0/8,::ffff:127.0.0.0/104,::1
```

postfix - main.cnf

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination unix check_policy_service: private / policyd-SPF reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, bl.spamcop.net reject_rbl_client, check_policy_service inet: 127.0.0.1: 10023
```

postfix - master.cf

```
policyd-spf unix - n n - 0 spawn
    user = policyd-spf argv = /usr/bin/policyd-spf
```

## mail.log

```
Oct 12 21:13:36 myserver policyd-spf [26371]: None; identity = helo; client-ip = 72,167,234,237; helo = p3nlsmtp12.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net; envelope-from=test@baddkim.com; receiver=mymail@myserver.com
Oct 12 21:13:36 myserver policyd-spf [26371]: None; identity = mailfrom; client-ip = 72,167,234,237; helo = p3nlsmtp12.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net; envelope-from=test@baddkim.com; receiver=mymail@myserver.com
Oct 12 21:13:36 myserver policyd-spf [26369]: Pass; identity = mailfrom; client-ip = 72,167,234,237; helo = p3nlsmtp12.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net; envelope-from=test@emailspooftest.com; receiver=mymail@myserver.com
Oct 12 21:13:36 myserver postfix / smtpd [22955]: BFA1981347: client = p3nlsmtp12.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net [72.167.234.237]
Oct 12 21:13:36 myserver postgrey [2322]: action = pass, reason = triplet found, client_name = p3nlsmtp12.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net, client_address = 72.167.234.237, sender=test@baddkim.com, recipient=mymail@myserver.com
Oct 12 21:13:36 myserver postfix / smtpd [26363]: C1ADE814FA: client = p3nlsmtp12.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net [72.167.234.237]
Oct 12 21:13:36 myserver postgrey [2322]: action = pass, reason = triplet found, client_name = p3nlsmtp12.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net, client_address = 72.167.234.237, sender=test@emailspooftest.com, recipient=mymail@myserver.com
```

Comment: you need DMARC policy set to reject to stop spoofing completely.

Comment: hi @architjn. I installed opendmarc but it rejects all emails. Any idea what could be wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64396880/postfix-opendmarc-reject-all-mails-5-7-1-rejected-by-dmarc-policy

Comment: First, try with `p=none` in the TXT value for the DMARC record, then debug and check what is the cause of the rejections.